# Song from final episode of Your Lie in April

Tags: music, your-lie-in-april

I've just finished Your Lie in April and the last song at the last part of the episode, not the duet or the performance, when kaori says I love you multiple times, a song is played in the background and when watching the dub the lyrics appear at the top of the screen, I can't for the life of me find that songs name, could anyone help? I like the song and am desperate to know the title and artist. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot comment in previous answer (low reputation) but Conman is correct

> http://shigatsu-wa-kimi-no-uso.wikia.com/wiki/Kirameki
>
> Kirameki (Kousei & Kaori Performance Ver.)  | Ver.) キラメキ ～公生とかをりの演奏 Ver.～

Answer (score 2):

I haven't got the episode in front of me to confirm, but I'm pretty sure you're talking about "Kirameki (Kaori and Kousei version)", a piano/violin duet version of the first ending theme. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaeED8YiY6k) is a YouTube version you can check against.

Comment: I've done a quick check: it's definitely some version of the ED, although I wasn't invested enough into this to check if it's indeed a piano/violin duet.